# Ruby on rails link_to syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, syntax, link-to

How do I use the `link_to` method, to utilize the `remove_tag` action?

issues_controller.rb

```
  def remove_tag
     @issue.remove_it
  end
```

issue.rb

```
  def remove_it
      self.users.delete(User.find(1))
   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "Remove Tag", remove_tag_issue_path(@issue) %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "Remove Tag", [:remove_tag, @issue] %>
```

And `remove_tag` action should be presented in routes as `member` for issue resources

Comment: as I understand this is shortcut for [polymorphic_url](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you have set your routes. You might need to use a named route for that action as it is not a standard resource route.

I suggest you read this:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

lint_to uses whatever is defined in routing